# What is the value of x?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that I wrote in  tag.

```
<script>
 var y = 1,
 x = y = typeof x; 
alert(x);
</script>
```

This will alert x as "undefined".

Please explain me how this is evaluated by Javascript compiler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Evaluation happens from right to left. So first `typeof(x)` evaluates and returns `undefined` to `y` which is then assigned to `x`

Comment: `var x, y;
y = 1;
y = typeof x;
x = y;
alert(x);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right to left.  Type of x before it is defined is, not surprisingly, undefined.

If you alert y in the same place you alert x, it'll be undefined as well, since you've set it to type of x

Answer (score 0):

Since `x` is not yet defined it will return 'undefined', then assign it to `y` and then assign the value of `y` (which is now undefined) to `x`.